# Merging two csv files if matched column then overwrite

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Example I have this two csv, how can overwrite the value of column `type` in  a.csv or replace if it matched both the string in column `fruit` in a.csv and b.csv

```
a.csv

fruit,name,type
apple,anna,A
banana,lisa,A
orange,red,A
pine,tin,A

b.csv

fruit,type
banana,B
apple,B
```

**How to output this:** OR how to overwrite

```
fruit,name,type
apple,anna,B
banana,lisa,B
orange,red,A
pine,tin,A
```

Im trying this using pandas but i dont know whats next

```
df1=pd.read_csv("sha1_vsdt.csv",delimiter=",",error_bad_lines=False,engine = 'python',quoting=3)
df2=pd.read_csv("final.csv",delimiter=",",error_bad_lines=False,engine = 'python',quoting=3)

df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='SHA-1', how='outer')
```

Comment: merge in python like merge in sql. `on='SHA-1'` this is column by which occurs merge (in your case I think you need `on='fruit'`. `how='outer'` this is swith which gave priority table (you can write `right`, `left` in you case `outer` without priority) More information with example you can read here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: can you help me please i really need to do this, im near to finishing it but im new to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your input  you have given

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv("a.csv")
df2=pd.read_csv("b.csv")
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='fruit', how='outer')
df['type_x'] = df['type_y'].combine_first(df['type_x'])
del df["type_y"]
df = df[pd.notnull(df['name'])]
```

input df1

```
    fruit   name    type
0   apple   anna    A
1   banana  lisa    A
2   orange  red     A
3   pine    tin     A
```

input df2

```
    fruit   type
0   banana  B
1   lemon   B
```

output

```
   fruit    name    type_x
0   apple   anna    A
1   banana  lisa    B
2   orange  red     A
3   pine    tin     A
```

if you have different files with different column names

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv("a.csv")
df2=pd.read_csv("b.csv")
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='fruit', how='outer')
df[df.columns[2]] = df[df.columns[3]].combine_first(df[df.columns[2]])
del df[df.columns[3]]
df = df[pd.notnull(df[df.columns[1]])]
```

Comment: it didn't overwrite my values in third column of a.csv

Answer (score 0):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and then rewrite missing unmatched values by original column values by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
#if possible duplicated fruit column
s = df2.drop_duplicates('fruit').set_index('fruit')['type']
df1['type'] = df1['fruit'].map(s).fillna(df1['type'])
print (df1)
    fruit  name type
0   apple  anna    B
1  banana  lisa    B
2  orange   red    A
3    pine   tin    A
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `merge`, this can be implemented via a simple `.loc`:

```
df2.set_index('fruit', inplace=True)
mask = df1.fruit.isin(df2.index)
df1.loc[mask, 'type'] = df2.loc[df1.loc[mask, 'fruit'], 'type'].values


    fruit   name    type
0   apple   anna    B
1   banana  lisa    B
2   orange  red     A
3   pine    tin     A
```

Comment: ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (344,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (343,)

Comment: It works per the dataset you provided, not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You can align indices, [`update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html), then `reset_index`:

```
# align indices
df1 = pd.read_csv(s1).set_index('fruit')
df2 = pd.read_csv(s2).set_index('fruit')

# update
df1.update(df2)

# reset index
res = df1.reset_index()

print(res)

    fruit  name type
0   apple  anna    B
1  banana  lisa    B
2  orange   red    A
3    pine   tin    A
```

**Setup**

```
from io import StringIO

s1 = StringIO("""fruit,name,type
apple,anna,A
banana,lisa,A
orange,red,A
pine,tin,A""")

s2 = StringIO("""fruit,type
banana,B
apple,B""")
```

Comment: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: @InUtero, Not sure what you mean, it works fine. I've added the data as per your post, if you need evidence.